# como puedo buscar en google una url compuesta?

Tags: php, google-chrome

Buenos días amigo quisiera saber como puedo buscar en google una url compuesta de la siguiente manera:

https://mysitio.precompro.com/select/

yo buscaba coincidencias en google así:

site:*.precompro.com/select

pero ahora se esta manejando así:

https://mysitio/select/

y quisiera poder automatizar la búsqueda, de ante mano gracias por su colaboración

Comment: Que has intentado al momento?, Por favor lee [ask]

Comment: esto es lo que he intentado:
select site:*.com
 pero me muestra todo lo que tiene la palabra selec ya se ha al principio o al final

Answer (score 0):

Google busca por defecto en subdominios. Si buscas site:precompro.com/select obtienes el resultado que esperas, creo. 
En https://www.google.com/advanced_search encuentras más información de cada opción de búsqueda avanzada.

Comment: gracias por responde lo que sucede es que el subdominio precompro ya no aplica, necesito buscar select en cualquier dominio o subdominio necesito lo concerniente a restaurantes

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que he leído, me da la sensación de que has desarrollado un aplicativo web y quieres ver en qué dominios se está usando, ¿es así?

Yo empezaría por lo que ya has mencionado: buscar [`site:*.com`]. Esto busca todos los sitios que tengan un dominio que acabe en `.com`.

En vez de eso, yo buscaría [`site:*.com/select`], ya que buscaría todos los dominios que acaben en `.com` y que contengan una página `select`.

La cuestión es que hay un montón de páginas que contienen la página `select`, ya que es una palabra muy común. Así que otra estrategia que podrías usar para obtener resultados más precisos sería incluir en los términos de búsqueda un trozo de texto que aparece en esas páginas.

En resumen, si las páginas que estás buscando incluyen el texto "Seleccionar carta", yo buscaría [`site:*.com/select "seleccionar carta"`].